# Is it possible to specify destination types in destructuring assignment?

Tags: rust

One may destructure tuple like this:

```
let (x,y,z) = xyz;
```

But is it possible to specify types for `x`,`y`, and `z`?
For example: `xyz` may be composed of `f32`-s but I'd like to get its components as `f64`-s. Unfortunately this code doesn't compile:

```
let (x:f64, y:f64, z:f64) = xyz;
```

Comment: Does it work if written like how a tuple type might be? `let (x, ..): (f64, ..) = ..` Nothing in https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2909-destructuring-assignment.html appears to apply..

Comment: Do note you can't implicitly cast from `f32`s to `f64`. You need to make the cast explicit with `as`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, you can annotate the type of the whole tuple:

```rust
let (x, y, z): (i32, &str, f32) = (10, "foo", 3.141516);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ff50850181f3cbbd9082380d62237af)

You can also partially specify them:

```rust
let (x, y, z): (i32, _, f32) = (10, "foo", 3.141516);
```

Note that ***this doesn't cast from one type to the others***. In rustlang it needs to be done explicetly.